# EXCEL - count number of non-empty rows by unique column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data looks like this: [with 10k rows and 26 something columns]

```
FID Year    I1  I2  I3  I4  I5
1   2009    a   b   c       
1   2010    a   d   e   g   
1   2011    g   f   h       
1   2011    h   f   j   i   k
1   2013    h   t   g   k   m
1   2014    a   b   c   d   
1   2014    e   d   f   c   l
1   2014    h   i   j   k   d
1   2014    a   b   d
```

I want the count of unique 'I's for every year. Output like this:

```
FID Year    Count(Unique)
1   2009    3
1   2010    4
1   2011    6
1   2013    5
1   2014    11
```

What I have tried till now:

- I tried this `=COUNTIF("$C2:$G2,"*")` and then summing for the same year. Until I realized that 'I's are being repeated.
- Then I tried concatenating all I's for the same year. Failed.
- Then I tried converting the data into the long format with [FID+Year] as the key. So that I can remove duplicates. But failed due to 'not enough memory' to perform the task.

Any help would be appreciated as to how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula that you need:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1;A1:E1)=1;1;0))
```

It is an array formula, thus you need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it.

If your values were numbers, it would have been easier. Like this:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:E1,A1:E1)>0,1))
```

It is not an array formula.

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to understand your answer. 1) there should be `,` instead of `;` right? 2) The `range` in `COUNTIF` is what exactly? I am assuming it is `C2:G2`. correct? 3) what does it mean to have a range in the criteria? 4) How is the formula taking into account the year and FID. 
5) I am also getting incorrect output.

Comment: @urwaCFC - it does not take the year in input, but it simply counts the unique values in a a given range. Thus the range should be the same. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this for you and here is the screenshot of the results:

[image]

Here is the formula you can try from `cell K2` and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$B$10,0),0,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,B2),5)<>"")/COUNTIF(OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$B$10,0),0,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,B2),5),OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$B$10,0),0,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,B2),5)&"")),0)
```

**Explanation:**

What this does is to use these two basic formulas.

`=SUMPRODUCT((range<>"")/COUNTIF(range,range&""))`, this is to find unique values in a range and also ignore the blanks

`=OFFSET(reference,rows,cols,height,width)`, this is to find the range that you want to evaluate

Hope this can solve your problem.